# Given two mixed independent random variables X,Y and Z=X+Y. Find the pdf of Z.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Given that  X,Y,Z are  all random variables with $Z=X+Y$ and $X,Y$ independent variables,where  $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim Bernoulli(p)$ .then,find pdf of $Z$.

By total probability laws we get the cdf of Z as folows: $F_z(t)=F_x(t)(1-p)+F_x(t-1)(p)$.
Now how do i find the pdf of Z? My attempt is that we diferentiate both RHS and LHS with respect to t since X is continous variable, and $Z=X+Y$ then Z is  a continous variable to. Is this argument valid? But then, how do i find domain of f(z) ,where f(z) is pdf of z ?Is the domain  every possible values of x+y thus $-\infty \le z \le \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is valid, though your notation is maybe a little confusing, since it's not clear what $F(Z=t)$ means.  If you write $F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)$ and $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$ for the CDFs of $Z$ and $X$ respectively, then the total probability law gives:
$$F_Z(t) = F_X(t)(1-p) + F_X(t-1)p, \quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$
This cdf is continuous (in fact, differentiable!), so that implies that $Z$ is a continuous random variable.  The pdf $f_z(t)$ of $Z$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ can be calculated by differentiating both sides, as you have guessed.  There is no special issue with the domain; it is all of $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  (You are correct that the domain should include all of the possible values of $x+y$ which is all of $\mathbb{R}$.)

The  domain would only become a concern if $F_X$ had a restricted domain.  For example, if $X$ had an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1$, then the CDF could be written:
$$F_X(x)=1-e^{-x}, \quad x\geq 0$$
If you tried to differentiate both sides of the above equation while ignoring the domain, you might get the answer:
$$f_Z(t) = e^{-t}(1-p)+e^{-(t-1)}p$$
but this is incorrect/incomplete.

Instead, you'd have to pay careful attention to the terms $F_X(t)$ and $F_X(t-1)$ and realize that since the complete CDF of $X$ is:
$$F_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & x < 0 \\
1-e^{-x}, & x \geq 0\\
\end{cases}$$
the complete CDF for $Z$ based on the law of total probability:
$$F_Z(t) = F_X(t)(1-p) + F_X(t-1)p, \quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$
needs to be broken down into multiple cases:
$$F_Z(t)=
\begin{cases}
0, & t < 0 \\
(1-e^{-t})(1-p), &0 \leq t < 1 \\
(1-e^{-t})(1-p) + (1-e^{-(t-1)})p, &t \geq 1
\end{cases}$$
and this *piecewise* differentiable function gives density:
$$f_Z(t)=
\begin{cases}
0, & t < 0 \\
e^{-t}(1-p), &0 \leq t < 1 \\
e^{-t}(1-p) + e^{-(t-1)}p, &t \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Again, none of this is an issue for your problem, because the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if we condition $Z$ on $Y$ we have a normal random variable of the form
$$
Z|Y=y\sim\mathcal N(y,1).
$$
Thus, denoting $\phi(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}$ as the standard normal density and $\Phi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t\phi(u)\,\mathrm du$ as the standard normal distribution, we have according to the law of total probability
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf P(Z\leq z)
&=\mathsf E(\mathsf P(Z\leq z|Y))\\
&=\mathsf E(\Phi(z-Y))\\
&=\sum_{y=0}^1\Phi(z-y)p^y(1-p)^{1-y}\\
&=\Phi(z)(1-p)+\Phi(z-1)p.
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $z$ gives the final result
$$
f_Z(z)=\phi(z)(1-p)+\phi(z-1)p.
$$
As for the support of $f_Z$, recall that $Z$ is the sum of a normal random variable, which can take on any real value, plus an integer. Therefore, the sum can be any real number, i.e., $f_Z$ has support for all $z\in\Bbb R$.

---

Here is a plot of $f_Z$ for $p=0.25$:

[image]